# "System Cant find file specified" in VS 2017 C# at calling (python) external executable

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, pyinstaller

I made a python executable using pyinstaller. The executable requires a dataset folder, which I have given it in same directory, and as for output it makes a txt file. All this works good alone.

I decided to use VS to create a front end and used `Process.Start()`, I put the required files in same directory of final exe (Bin/debug folder) and as well as in "Solution Explorer", but I'm getting an "System cannot find file specified error". I also tried to use `Process.Start(@Application.StartupPath+"\naivebayes.exe")`
but getting same error.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I want to make a front end with buttons and each button to call a separate exe file and publish all the files together in a single project, what am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `\` in your specified path tells the runtime too look for your `naivebayes.exe` in the root directory of the drive (which I assume wasn't your goal).

You should specify your filename without a leading `\` (or use a leading dot even before it, since `.\` construct would point relatively).

Comment: using .\ fixed the problem